# Comparison between two rows and change value

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

i have a matrix 20 rows and 20 columns,
If the value 1 in the row 5 the column take 0

```
matric=[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0; 
     1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ; 
     0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1;
     0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1;
     0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1;
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1;
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;];
if (matric(5,:)==1)
matric(1:5,1:end)=0;end
```

I try to compare the second row and the 5 row
If we have "1" in row 2 and row 5
The row 2 take 0

```
if (matric(5,:)==matric(2,:)==1)
matric(2,1:end)=0;end
```

do you have an idea

Thank you

The desired output is:

```
 matric=[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0; 
     1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 ;2row will change 
     0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1;
     0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1;
     0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1; % 5 row
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **logical indexing**.

I strongly encourage you to read the following references:

- Mathworks documentation page: [Find Array Elements That Meet a Condition](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/find-array-elements-that-meet-a-condition.html)
- Loren on the Art of MATLAB blog entry: [Logical Indexing – Multiple
  Conditions](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/02/20/logical-indexing-multiple-conditions/)

---

Use the following lines of code:

> Put `0` in all those columns that have a value of `1` in row 5:

```
matric(:, matric(5, :) == 1) = 0;
```

> Put `0` in all those columns of row 2 that have a value of `1` both in rows 2 and 5:

```
matric(2, matric(2, :) == matric(5, :)) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use logical indexing to achieve this. Now I must say I am a bit confused by what exactly you want to achieve based on your description, but based on the your code the first statement can be done as follow:

```
matric(1:5,matric(5,:)==1) = 0;
```

and the second would look like:

```
matric(2,matric(5,:)==1 & matric(2,:)==1)=0;
```